# I'm the Village Idiot

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

A payment for the kings,
A child of rock who sings,
The sign says you can't do it,
In Spain, you might go through it.

You will find me in a void,
I was coined by Sigmund Freud,
Above you'll find me in each of these,
If three is easy, I'm a breeze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> the id?

A payment for the kings,

> With help from John, quid, qu-id!

A child of rock who sings,

> Kid Rock, k-id

The sign says you can't do it,

> A sign might say trespassing is forbidden, forb-id-den

In Spain, you might go through it.

> Madrid is a city in Spain, Madr-id

You will find me in a void,

> The word 'id' is in the word 'void', vo-id

I was coined by Sigmund Freud,'

> He invented the concept of the id, the ego, and the superego

Above you'll find me in each of these,

> Points out that the answers to the first stanza contain the word 'id'

If three is easy, I'm a breeze.

> Might be an id-ego-superego reference?  John helped again, 'id' only has two letters.

Title clue:

> The village Id-iot

Comment: That's all correct. Kid, Forbid, Madrid, and what (how much?) payment to a king? If three is easy, then... two _letters_ should be even easier.

Comment: I've got nothing on the king payment.  Tithe, tax, gold, frankincense, myrrh...if we're going British I could give him quid?

Comment: A payment for the kings: Feudal a-id

Comment: Yes, I think you could.  That's what I was looking for. If you were to say that the term didn't really exist (which I did look up, but found inconclusive) during the middle-ages, or perhaps its value was too large for the common tax-payer, I'd say, well, sorry. But that's what I was looking for!  Good job!

Comment: I'm terrible at history, but it's probably safe to say they had quid at some point while having a king, right?  Thanks!

Comment: I think that's safe!  :)